# neo4j How to cahe all the nodes and relations to RAM for importing query performance

Tags: neo4j

I have installed the APOC Procedures and used "CALL apoc.warmup.run."

The result is as follow:

```
pageSize
8192

nodesPerPage  nodesTotal  nodesLoaded  nodesTime
546           156255221   286182       21

relsP‌erPage   relsTotal   rel‌sLoaded   relsTime
240           167012639   695886       8

tot‌alTime
30
```

It looks like the neo4j server only caches part of nodes and relations.
But I want it to cache all the nodes and relationships in order to improve query performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for all data to be cached, you need a [page cache large enough](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/performance/#page-cache-sizing).

Then, the problem is not that Neo4j does not cache all it can, it's more of a bug in the `apoc.warmup.run` procedure: it retrieves the number of nodes (resp. relationships) in the database, and expects them to all have [ids between 1 and that number of nodes](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.0.4.1/src/main/java/apoc/warmup/Warmup.java#L44) (resp. [relationships](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.0.4.1/src/main/java/apoc/warmup/Warmup.java#L47)). However, it's not true if you've had some churn in the DB, like creating more nodes then deleting some of them.

I believe that could be fixed by using another query instead:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN count(n) AS count, max(id(n)) AS maxId
```

as profiling it shows about the same number of DB hits as the number of nodes, and takes about 650 ms on my machine for 1.4 million nodes.

---

**Update:** I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/131) on the subject.

---

**Update 2**

While the issue with the ids is real, I missed the real reason why the procedure reports reading far less nodes: it only reads [one node per page](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.0.4.1/src/main/java/apoc/warmup/Warmup.java#L38) (assuming they're stored sequentially), since it's the pages that are cached. With the current values, that means trying to read one node every 546 nodes. It happens that *156255221 ÷ 546 = 286181*, and with node `0` that makes it 286182 nodes loaded.

Comment: I using the query,it return 'count:156255221 maxId:156255220'                                           
First of all,My machine have more than 42G free memory.Although I didn't configure the **dbms.memory.pagecache.size**,but i think it's enough.       
Second,I never try to create or delete nodes.

Comment: The first comment was a general remark, I don't know your setup and can't comment on it. Apparently, you did create a few nodes, since you have 156 millions of them.

Comment: **With the current values, that means trying to read one node every 546 nodes. It happens that 156255221 ÷ 546 = 286181, and with node 0 that makes it 286182 nodes loaded.** dose it cache all the nodes and relation into the RAM. could you describle more detail for me about how to cache all the data.

Comment: I have check the sysinfo carefully.The Page Cache column value is "No statistics available"  Dose that means no page cache at all.It's very confusing

Comment: The cache is for *pages* (of nodes and relationships data). By hitting one element per page (which loads the whole page), they are all cached after the warmup, assuming the cache is big enough. As for `:sysinfo`, you've probably hit a [known bug](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7806) on the master of a cluster.

Comment: I am using the 3.03 community edition,and only installed single instance.   **I am wondering whether this community eidtion support caching all the nodes and relationships data**

Comment: The another question is why the second time "allshortestpaths" query is always faster than the first time.   I think the neo4j must  cache data while the first time querying.but i have searched useful information about this.

Comment: Neo4j runs on the JVM, which will compile byte code to native code as needed, as well as perform optimizations once it gets enough information about the runtime. You can expect the first execution of anything to be slower (there's also class loading and initialization involved). As for the metrics in `:sysinfo`, as mentioned at the bottom of the block, "Note: some metrics only available in Neo4j Enterprise"; but even if the metrics are not available in the Community Edition, I'm pretty sure the page cache is.

Comment: I have two question now. **1** For the allshortestpaths cypher query,the first execution often cost more than 2 seconds,and **the longer path length between the query nodes,the more time the first execution cost** the second excution only cost about 100ms.  I don't think JVM account for such huge difference.

Comment: **2** Though  page cache is  available in the Community Edition,I am wondering how many graph data it cached. **Quoting from Neo4j Operation Manual,  the graph data from disk is cached into memory**,So I think the RAM Memory should have increased a lot ,when using the "apoc.warmup.run".but the RAM memory didn't change at all actually

Comment: **1**, at some point you have to profile yourself if you're really interested in the why; don't guess, measure. Compare the APOC warmup with Cypher queries that _will_ read everything (and take longer), like `MATCH (n) RETURN count(n), max(id(n))` and `MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(r), max(id(r))`. **2**, it depends how you check the memory usage (you don't say), as it doesn't use the JVM heap, but memory-mapped files, I think.

Comment: I am a rookie to neo4j and have did some test on the query performance before and after using the APOC warmup.But i didn't find any evidence.  **Compare the APOC warmup with Cypher queries that will read everything (and take longer), like MATCH (n) RETURN count(n), max(id(n)) and MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(r), max(id(r)).**  dose it mean i should use the cyper queries before and after the APOC warmup.             I use the task manager to monitor the memory usage.

Comment: You want to know if the warmup is effective, so compare the execution time of your actual query (restarting Neo4j between tests) in 3 scenarios, where you run the query after: no warmup, the APOC warmup, or the manual Cypher warmup (my 2 queries counting all nodes and all relationships). If there's no real difference in any of these runs, maybe your query is _not_ I/O-bound after all. About measuring the memory usage, the task manager seems a bit limited (what type of memory does it actually measure?).

Comment: It really confuse me,the query i used is 'allshortestpaths'.it is obvious that the server needs to traverse lots of nodes.  Is it neccessary that the machine must has  available memory about 120% of the sum size of all the store.db files. quoting from The Neo4j Operations Manual v3.0(6.3.2 page cahce sizing)

Comment: Have we solved this issue? Im facing the same, like ram usage does not change if running the warmup. I'm using Neo4j 3.08